# Why do some methods of built-in types operate in-place and some don't?

Tags: python, list, function, methods

```
dog = 'penny'
print(dog.title())

dog_names = ['pete', 'luke', 'shane']
print(dog_names.remove('shane'))
```

Why does Python return an output of `Penny` for `dog.title()` but `None` for 
`dog_names.remove('shane')`? Why can I not print the list `dog_name` with the method `remove` while I can use the method `title` on `dog`?

I understand that I get `None` because `dog_name.remove` has no return, but how does `dog.title` have a return?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

Comment: [`list.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) modifies the list in-place, it is convention for all methods that modify an object in-place to return `None`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inplace functions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126403/inplace-functions-in-python)

Comment: A better duplicate target: [Why some methods change the object permanently while others don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52469732/7851470)

Answer (score 1):

The `title()` function is a pre-defined function in Python which is used to covert the first character of the string into uppercase and the remaining characters into lowercase and return a new string.
in your example if you run `print(dog)` you can see that `penny` is all lowercase, but if you run `print(dog.title())` you can see that the first letter in `Penny` which is `P` is uppercase and the remaining is lowercase

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer your question, first, you need to understand what's being returned.

When calling `print` on a function or method, it will display the returned value. 
With that being said, you can check the return value of both functions from the documentation

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

> list.remove(x) Remove the first item from the list whose value is x.
>   It is an error if there is no such item.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.title

> str.title() **Return a titlecased** version of the string where words
>   start with an uppercase character and the remaining characters are
>   lowercase.

- Notice how `title()` returns the titled case string, that's why it's printed.
- On the other hand `remove()` doesn't return anything, in this case, python has a default return value of `None` ([Source](http://dvalts.io/2018/07/26/Return-statements.html)) that's why it's printed when calling `remove()`

Answer (score 0):

A `function`/`method` in any programming language performs a specific task. A task could be performed on the inputs passed to the function. After performing the task, the function may want to give the result back to the caller of the function. It may do that by:

1. By modifying the parameters passed to it or By altering the object on which method was called. (For example, `remove()` method of list data type)
2. By returning the result to the caller. (`title()` method)
3. A combination of (1) and (2)

Your [remove()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) method doesn't return anything back to the caller. Instead it just deletes an element from the list. To print the list after removing an element:

```
dog_names.remove('shane')
print(dog_names)
```